# Fix held broken packages on debian?

Tags: debian, apt

I want to begin exploring moving myself away from google apps, because it's expensive, and it looks like citadel has all of the groupware functions I need. So I am trying to install citadel-suite with:

> apt-get install citadel-suite

But it returns:

> citadel-suite: depends: citadel-mta but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Well, yes. It does require citadel-mta. That's half the point. So why is it not going to be installed?  What broken packages do I have held?  Why are they broken?  Why are they held? I didn't hold them. Or break them, for that matter.

The problem with apt-get is that, for the 10 years I have been using it, it has, to borrow an Apple phrase, just worked.  Now that it isn't, I'm rather at a loss.  I did try the -f switch, but it didn't help.  I haven't made any modifications to /etc/apt/sources.list, so I can't revert them.  What should I try next?

Comment: I'd be glad to here about your experience with `citadel`. do you try the --fix-missing --fix-broken and other ?

Comment: I suggest you study the situation with `aptitude`. Its dependency solver isn't as good as `apt-get`'s, but since it's an interactive tool it makes inspecting the system's state much easier.

Comment: If I get it installed, I'll let you know. According to the feature list, it seems to do everything I need but two-factor authentication, and I can handle that through the VPN.

Comment: @badp: Actually, it's dependency solver seems to be better. aptitude install citadel-suite proposes a solution. It wants to remove the virtual package mail-transport-agent. I didn't even know I had that installed, so removing it is probably fine. Why didn't apt just do that?

Comment: @fastfinge Yeah, sometimes `aptitude` can get out of situations `apt-get` won't begin to touch, sometimes `aptitude` starts going North and suggesting you uninstall half of your system to fix a dependency with texlive documentation. :)

Comment: what do you get when you run `apt-get install citadel-mta` ?

Comment: Please post `apt-cache policy citadel-suite citadel-mta`. Also, please post your version/release of Debian. Also the output of `apt-cache policy`.

Comment: @Lawrence and Faheem: Thanks, but I already got an answer and accepted it. Aptitude why-not was what I wanted, and told me everything I needed to know. I apparently couldn't find it on google because I was searching for information on apt-get and didn't know about aptitude.

Comment: @Kiwy: Citadel seems to be a really good product!  The website is snappy, full text works, and most things function out of the box. The only problem is that the Debian packages aren't very good.  Debian asked me what administrative user I wanted, and then forgot to create that user in citadel, leaving me with a citadel system with no administrators. But you can easily fix it by running /usr/lib/citadel-server/setup and using the Citadel process not the debian one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"... But it is not going to be installed" generally means that a serious dependency conflict will ensue if it's allowed to go on.

Try the following command:

```
aptitude why-not citadel-mta
```

`why-not` basically checks dependencies and returns the reasons it would have to not fill a particular dependency automatically.

In the case of my system at home:

```
shadur@leviathan:~$ aptitude why-not citadel-mta
i   exim4-daemon-light Conflicts mail-transport-agent
p   citadel-mta        Provides  mail-transport-agent
```

Apparently citadel-mta is a full-on MTA and will therefore replace whatever mail-transport-agent package you currently have installed. Explicitly telling it to install citadel-mta as well should be enough to break the deadlock.

**NOTE**: Doing so means your current mail server software will be replaced by the one that comes with citadel. Make *very* sure that that's what you want before you do this.

Comment: This is a testing server, being used to explore how well the citadel groupware server works as a gmail replacement, on a test domain, with no user data. So that's exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I found that installing with `aptitude` rather than `synaptic` or `apt-get` ended up working.  `aptitude` is smarter and offered me resolution to the problem.

Edit:  I did have to skip the first resolution suggested to get one that actually worked.