# Broken KDE Plasma desktop after adding sid repository under Debian

Tags: debian, apt, plasma

I have Debian 8.2 installed on a VirtualBox VM and I added the unstable (sid) repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list` without removing any other repositories and afterwards I ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get autoremove`. Before this, I had Plasma 4 installed, I was hoping that adding this repository would give me Plasma 5, but instead I have no Plasma desktop installed at all, or so it seems. Whenever I run:

```
apt-get install kde-full
```

I get the error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kde-full : Depends: kde-plasma-desktop (>= 5:84) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: kde-plasma-netbook (>= 5:84) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: kdeartwork (>= 4:4.11.3) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: kdenetwork (>= 4:4.11.3) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: kdeutils (>= 4:4.11.3) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: kdepim (>= 4:4.11.3) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: kdeplasma-addons (>= 4:4.11.3) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: kde-standard (>= 5:84) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: kdewebdev (>= 4:4.11.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

whenever I try to install specific Plasma components using `apt-get install` like by running `apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop` I get similar errors, with the exact same final line (i.e., `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`).

## Troubleshooting

As far as troubleshooting goes, I have Googled `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` and found the questions "*[Fix held broken packages on debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121149/fix-held-broken-packages-on-debian)*" and "*[E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)*" and tried:

```
apt-get install -f kde-full
```

which returned the same error as running without the `-f` option. I also ran `apt-get -f install` and it just returned:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I have also tried running:

```
aptitude why-not kde-full
```

and

```
aptitude why-not kde-plasma-desktop
```

and both returned:

```
Unable to find a reason to remove ...
```

where ... is the package name provided after `aptitude why-not`. While `apt-mark showhold` returned no output whatsoever.